# How to assign values to a map for later use in Kotlin class?

Tags: typescript, kotlin

I want to create a map of key value pairs in Kotlin inside a class that can be arbitrarily updated and referenced. I have read that a MutableMap may be what I need since I can update is at any time. In Typescript my code would look like the following. How can I write something similar in Kotlin?

```
type Callback = (id: string) => void | null;

interface DataMap {
  streetNumber: number | null;
  streetName: string | null;
  callback: Callback | null;
}

const dataMap: DataMap = {
  streetNumber: null,
  streetName: null,
  callback: null,
}

// do something later..
const doSomething = (streetName: string, callback: Callback): void => {
  dataMap.streetName = streetName;
  dataMap.callback = callback;
}

// and then..
const printData = (): void => {
  console.log(dataMap.streetName) // streetName is printed
}
```

Comment: I don't know type script, but this *looks* like you can just use a data class. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: I agree with @Sweeper, it looks like you can use a regular class or data class for this. You only need a map if the keys themselves are dynamic (the names of the properties). If in TS you have an interface with specific property names, you can do the same in Kotlin.

Comment: As a side question, why can `Callback` return void *or* null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need a map if the keys themselves are dynamic (the names of the properties). If in TS you have an interface with specific property names, you can do the same in Kotlin.

A somewhat equivalent code in Kotlin could be:

```kotlin
typealias Callback = (id: String) -> Unit?

data class DataMap(
    var streetNumber: Int?,
    var streetName: String?,
    var callback: Callback?,
)

val dataMap = DataMap(
    streetNumber = null,
    streetName = null,
    callback = null,
)

// do something later..
fun doSomething(streetName: String, callback: Callback) {
    dataMap.streetName = streetName
    dataMap.callback = callback
}

// and then..
fun printData() {
    println(dataMap.streetName) // streetName is printed
}
```

Although we would usually avoid global variables.